# How to pronounce "80x86", "Linux 2.6", and "Figure 3-1"?

Tags: pronunciation

As a foreigner, I have been confused with such a simple question:

How to pronounce "80x86", "Linux 2.6", and "Figure 3-1"?

Comment: Is "80x86" an arithmetic expression? ie. "80*86", or literally the characters as given? The context could alter how it is said.

Comment: @w3d No, it's the type of CPU instructions.

Comment: In that case, how you would pronounce "80x86" is dependent on the subject, not specifically the English language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will address the more general question of how to pronounce different kinds of digit strings that don’t represent numbers.

- Terms of art such as “80x86” have unique pronunciations that you must simply learn.

  > - eighty ex eighty-six (80x86)
  > - eighty eighty-six (8086)
  > - ex eighty-six (x86)
  > - oh ess ten (OS X)
- Version numbers are pronounced in full, with decimal points pronounced “point”.

  > - Linux two-point-six (2.6)
  > - My software is in version one-point-oh-two (1.02)
  > - We are working toward a one-point-ten-point-oh release (1.10.0)
- Figure and section names are said as sequences of numbers with pauses between.

  > - Refer to Figure three-ten (Fig. 3-10)
  > - This is described in Section three-one-four (§3.1.4)
- American phone numbers are pronounced digitwise, in clusters of area code, exchange, and number:

  > Dial six-oh-three, five-five-five, one-two-three-four (603-555-1234)

Comment: 8086 and 80x86 are different things so why would you pronounce them identically?

Comment: Eighty-ex-eighty-six would be the correct pronunciation for 80x86. 80x86 includes 8086 (and, parenthetically, 8088), but they don't mean the same thing. 80x86 also includes 80186, 80286, 80386, 80486, etc.

Comment: Pronouncing OS X as written is at least as common as pronouncing it OS Ten, though, and from Mavericks onwards, I believe it is even the officially used pronunciation (though I'm going here purely on memory, from recent keynotes).

Comment: Engineers often use _dot_ instead of _point_ for version numbers: _two dot six._ More rarely, they will read them like a figure name: _two-six._ I like the approach you took to answering this, however: +1.

Comment: Also, as I noted in my comment on teylyn’s answer, engineers often drop portions of the code number in speech, reducing _2.6_ to _’dot-six._ Arguably that’s an abbreviation rather than a variant pronunciation, although I feel that’s a distinction without a difference.

Answer (score 3):

There are different answers to the different samples in the question.

"80x86" - It depends on the context. On the [site that discusses the nature of 80X86 programming,](http://mysite.du.edu/~etuttle/math/8086.htm) the "x" is dropped in the first sentence and the rest of the article only refers to "8086", which I assume would be pronounced "eighty-eighty-six"

The linux sample, as far as I am concerned is "Linux two point six"

The figure sample, as far as I am concerned is "Figure three [pause] one"

Comment: It doesn't depend on the context. 80x86 is an architecture, 8086 is a processor.

Comment: What I said. It depends on the context. If you discuss the architecture, the wording will be different than if you discuss the processor. So, you need to be clear about the context that is discussed. You cannot expect one correct answer for a phrase that can be either X or Y. You need to provide the context for a correct answer.

Comment: It doesn't depend on context. 80x86 is _always_ the architecture and pronounced ‘eighty x eighty-six’, while 8086 is always the processor, pronounced ‘eighty eighty-six’. If some people use one to mean the other, that doesn't make either context-specific; it just makes their writing nonsensical. Of course, if you don't have _any_ context, you'd most likely pronounce them ‘eighty by eighty-six’ (as in the measurements of an area) and ‘eight thousand and eighty-six’, respectively.

Comment: Engineers _often_ drop elements from code numbers like these when saying them aloud. _80x86_ can be pronounced _eighty-ex-eighty-six_ or _eighty-’-eighty-six_ or _’ex-eighty-six_ or just _’eighty-six,_ much as you might pronounce _1986_ as _’eighty-six._ Likewise, somebody might say _’dot-six_ instead of _two-dot-six._ Arguably these are abbreviations rather than variant pronunciations, but I think that’s splitting hairs overly fine.

Comment: 8086 is an abbreviated  part number for an electronic component (eg D8086), and would follow general usage for part numbers. 80x86 is a wildcard construction (80286, 80386, 80486, whatever...) based on that, used to describe the architecture common to these parts.

Answer (score 2):

`eighty-x-eighty-six`, `two-dot-six`, `three-one`.